# My Patch() does not put NULL into a NULL-able column of my SQL table

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have an SQL table with a column that looks like this:

MyColumn nvarchar NULL

I have created a simple Canvas app wit a Gallery whose data source is the table. In the Gallery I have a Text input component attached to MyColumn column. When an end-user enters blank string (or clears the component, as we could call it) I see that a blank string was put into the DB column MyColumn.
I do not want the blank string in the DB in this situation; I want NULL. I have tried to resolve the problem this way: in OnChange property of the |Text input control I wrote this:

```
Patch('MyTable',
    ThisItem,
    {
        MyColumn:
        If(
            IsBlank(t_TextInputComponent.Text), 
                Blank(), 
            t_TextInputComponent.Text
        )
    }
)
```

But this has not worked: a blank string was put into the DB column anyway.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try:

```
Patch('MyTable',
    ThisItem,
    {
        MyColumn:
        If(
            !IsBlank(t_TextInputComponent.Text), 
                t_TextInputComponent.Text
        )
    }
)
```

Loosely translates to: `If text.text is not blank, then patch text.text`

You don't have to specify the `else` case. As long as `MyColumn` contains a `NULL` value already, this should preserve it from being overwritten.